# remove the string after "x" character

Tags: regex, bash

I have a large text file in this format:

```
israilxnoun turizmxnoun bakanlıkxnoun ikixadj günxnoun öncexpostp ayırxverb
```

I want to remove the string which comes after then `x` character. The output that I want:

```
  israil turizm bakanlık iki gün önce ayır
```

How can I do that with a bash script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Through sed,

```
sed 's/x[^[:space:]]*//g' file
```

or

```
sed 's/x\S*//g'
```

Comment: Think some sed won't support `\S+`